# Sort of slanted box shape in css?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make this shape in css:

[image]

but am sort of lost how to do so. I have a triangle made right now with this:

```
var resY = $(window).height;
var resX = $(window).width;

$('#slide1-container').css({'border-bottom-width': resY, 'border-left-width': .4*resX});
```

because for some reason percentages/vh/vw wasn't working with border-width in css (not sure if it's supported?)

I'm unsure of how to make it from triangle -> the shape I have pictured. Any suggestions?

Thanks for any help! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is this?

http://jsfiddle.net/xVzMZ/

```
#shape {
    border-bottom: 150px solid black;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: looks perfect! Would you mind explaining just how the border-left is actually making it slanted? I'm kind of confused as to how that's actually moving the shape of the box

Comment: @shanling: The join between two borders is slanted like that, and the bottom border is tall. (So the triangular part ends up being 150 pixels tall and 50 pixels wide.) Does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/xVzMZ/1/

Comment: The "box" is actually the bottom border of the div, and it uses the fact that the corners for each side of the border are angled to make that shape, if that made sense.

Answer (score 1):

A right border, like:

```css
#trapezoid {
    border-bottom: 2em solid black;
    border-left: 1em solid transparent;
    border-right: 1.5em solid black;
    width: 0;
}
```

[Seems to look right.](http://rninty.me/files/trapezoid.html) It’s not hard to adjust.